# How to generate excel file with one worksheet containing multiple tables/pivot in oracle plsql?

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql

I wish to generate excel file with one data set to be pasted from cell range [A-E] and pivot table from [G-I].
Is this possible using oracle plsql ,by creating a procedure?
I have written SQL Queries to get the results.

[image: PFA screenshot for reference]

Comment: There is no way of doing this with functionality provided by Oracle. Have a look at [Anton Scheffer's library](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/). It's the best of its kind. However, what you're trying to do is tricky (and arguably poor practice) so you may have to bend the code to achieve the desired layout. A separate worksheet for the pivot might be easier.

Comment: hi APC thanks for your reply but can you please explain why according to you this is a poor practice??

Comment: I agree with APC, but I'll mention that there is a very powerful set of libraries/packages for `perl` that creates excel files. Not sure if it can do this for you AND it would be a big learning curve (even with perl experience (IMHO)). Good luck.

Comment: Did you explore the utl_file API from oracle to write into file?